# How do I reinstall Windows 7 without losing data if Windows does not start-up?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

How can I reinstall windows 7 without losing all my files if I cannot load windows? I receive a BSOD when trying to load windows. But, the windows 7 install only gives two options New install or login to windows for reinstall.

I don't understand why you can't reinstall from outside of Windows.

Edit: this is being fixed so someone. Naturally everyone says restore from a backup but majority of consumers don't backup or know how. This is the error i'm receiving 
Stop: 0x0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A97E8, 0xFFFFFFFFC000000D, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000000000000000)

Yes i've don't chkdsk, and a countless of other recovery methods. Is it possible to reinstall Windows 7 without logging in? That's the question I want to know, in the past windows versions it was possible.

Comment: There is a plethora of information on dealing with this scenario on here and on the Internet in general.  The usual first answer is "Restore from your backups -- you made backups, right?". Perhaps start by looking up the STOP code the BSoD is giving you.  As-is this question is too vague and shows little effort aside from putting in a disk. :(

Comment: @techie007 see above... my original question seem to be over looked by the down voters. Which is/was can I reinstall windows 7 from outside of windows. I've done all an more attempts at fixes as well as googling. Everyone talks about reintalling from within windows but I just want to know yes or no is it possible to reinstall from outside of windows? the fixes i've tried all of them and more

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing your existing installation first. You can do so by pressing **F8** when you boot your computer, and then select the option **Repair Your Computer**. If that doesn't work, you can boot from a Windows 7 DVD/USB stick to try and repair your computer. You might also want to try System Restore in Recovery options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: tried repairing, last know good configuration, repaired bootrec, safe mode, etc ... no luck. my only option is to reinstall windows, but Windows requires you to login to windows in order to reinstall. I can only do a complete new install from outside of windows. In which I don't want to do if possible

Comment: What exactly is the error you get when you try to boot your computer?